# Customizing Facebook & Google+ login buttons in Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus

[I want these buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owUR8.png)

[I have these buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FahLP.png)

I want to customize my Facebook and Google+ login buttons, can someone help me with that? 
**These are my layout codes**

```
  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp" />


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using default UI components you should Use **Button**. Do Whatever design you want. Clicking on button you have to code for Login/Sign up or whatever you want.

This is example only.

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/loginButtonFacebook"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/shape_blue_button"
 android:text="@string/facebook_txt" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/loginButtonGoogle"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@drawable/shape_red_button"
 android:text="@string/google_txt" />
```

Facebook:
In Your activity do following:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    // Use Access Token loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // Handle cancel event
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    //Handle Error event
                }
            });
    }
  }
```

Button Click event:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList(
                        "email", "public_profile", "user_friends"));
```

Manifest File-

```
<provider
android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderYOUR_APP_ID"
android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: loginButton =(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email")); This is what I'm using, I won't be able to use the same with a Button type. 
Help me out!

Comment: @YashUbale, If this answer is helpful then mark it as an accepted answer or gives plus vote.